# javascript is not running in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with running javascript codes in may pages.
I tried testing my code in xampp and it was working.
but I can not see them when  I add them to my pages or my posts in my host and I installed wordpress again and it wasn't  working.
Please help me

Comment: Could you provide us with some more information, are these manually added JavaScript files? How do you register them? In a child theme? Did you manually create a plug-in and register them there? Do you want to load them in the front-end, or back-end?

Comment: I want to load them in the front-end

Comment: And what does your code look like to actually load them in the front-end? Or do you use some other plug-in?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.smartform.ir/form/export.php?id=8863"></script>

Comment: this is my code

Comment: i want to add it  to my  home page

Comment: and i tryed different codes and the werent working either

Comment: You are trying to load a PHP file, not a JavaScript file, that is never going to work. I can help you but I need to know a few things. Do you have FTP acccess to your server? What theme do you use in WordPress and did you already create/have a child-theme for it?

Comment: im using betheme

Comment: i have ftp access

Comment: i didnt create child theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can include JavaScript files in WordPress, I will give you one example using your child theme.

First you need to validate whether or not you actually have a child theme. Use FTP to login to you server and go to the wp-contents/themes directory. There you will see all your installed themes (in your case betheme). If you do not have a child theme follow these steps:

1. Create a new directory in your themes folder (betheme-child).
2. Upload your JavaScript file in this directory (for example script.js)
3. Create a new file called functions.php and add the following code to it: (surrounded by php opening and closing tags):

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_scripts');`

```
function enqueue_child_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('child-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js');
}
```

4. Login to your wp-admin and navigate to your themes
5. Enable your child theme instead of your normal theme.
6. Go to the front-page of your website, look at the page source and check if your JavaScript file is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cloudflare, turn off minify JS.